# Xamarin.iOS binding library cannot use the SecKey API from the Security framework

Tags: ios, security, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-binding

I created a binding library from an objective-c framework. It works but it cannot use SecKey's encryption api in the Security framework. Library used it for the api request. Is Security framework not fully supported in Xamarin.iOS? Or is it not working when binding library used it?

Note: By the way I added this line to native framework for dependency:

```
 <Frameworks>Foundation CFNetwork CoreFoundation Security</Frameworks>
```

Update 1:

This is the device log:

```
Trust evaluate failure: [leaf AnchorTrusted]
DemoX[10647]/1#-1 LF=22 add Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-34018 "Client has neither application-identifier nor keychain-access-groups entitlements" UserInfo={NSDescription=Client has neither application-identifier nor keychain-access-groups entitlements}
SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, pid=10438
SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: DemoX[10039]/0#-1 LF=0
nw_protocol_boringssl_signal_connected(728) [C13.1:2][0x7fbe21309f80] TLS connected [version(0x0303) ciphersuite(TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) group(0x001d) signature_alg(0x0601) alpn(http/1.1) resumed(0) offered_ticket(0) false_started(0) ocsp_received(0) sct_received(0) connect_time(1811ms) flight_time(144ms) rtt(72ms) write_stalls(0) read_stalls(5)]    
Trust evaluate failure: [leaf AnchorTrusted]
Trust evaluate failure: [leaf AnchorTrusted TemporalValidity]
```

Update 2:

When I run the framework with the XCode below lines appears but not in the my Xamarin.iOS app

```
inserted <keys,kcls=0,klbl=,atag=5253415574696C5F5075624B6579,
crtr=0,type=42,bsiz=0,esiz=0,sdat=2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000,
edat=2001-01-01 00:00:00+0000,agrp=A7PT8PDBPQ.com.test.app,sync=0,
musr=,|otherAttr,tomb=0,rowid=9,cdat=2020-11-07 11:02:34 +0000,mdat=2020-11-07 11:02:34+0000,pdmn=ak,
sha1=24BB5BBEE125D6A051E08EA2CB72469A0C62042F,v_Data=<?>,
UUID=********-****-****-****-************,
persistref=,clip=0> from <SecDbConnection rw open>
```

and

```
deleted 
<keys,kcls=0,klbl=,atag=5253415574696C5F5075624B6579,crtr=0,type=42,
bsi=,esiz=0,sdat=2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000,edat=2001-01-01 00:00:00
+0000,agrp=A7PT8PDBPQ.com.test.app,sync=0,musr=,
|otherAttr,tomb=0,rowid=7,cdat=2020-11-07 11:01:55 
+0000,mdat=2020-11-07 11:01:55 +0000,pdmn=ak,
sha1=F1A9A4EC0C5AC67D354C9D7602E118B8DF5EFAF5,
v_Data=<?>,accc=310C300A0C0470726F740C02616B,
UUID=********-****-****-****-************,
persistref=,clip=0> from <SecDbConnection rw open>
```

Comment: Exactly which Security framework methods are you trying to call?

Comment: In the library, they get the public key from server and make it a SecKeyRef, after that Encrypt it with this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1643957-seckeycreateencrypteddata?language=objc

Comment: `SecKeyRef` are just `IntPtr` in Xamarin.iOS and `SecKeyCreateEncryptedData` entry point is defined as a `DllImport` as it is a `C` call (https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/blob/4a050c5ae67cf6cc1144af6a7f03707491b5c0a2/src/Security/Certificate.cs#L928) Xamarin has created wrapper methods called `CreateEncryptedData`, `CreateDecryptedData`, etc... to make those native C calls easier to use (they are all defined in `Security/Certificate.cs` file I linked.

Comment: Ok but, why the library can't use it?

Comment: What problem are YOU having with the binding of the library then(?), since it is a ObjC-based framework it would have nothing to do with Xamarin, but if the binding library interfaces that you created are wrong, than the library might be getting the wrong data....

Comment: Problem is, encryption failed when I use library in a demo app. It needs to send encrypted key with the api request.

Comment: @SushiHangover is Security included in Xamarin.iOS.dll? I cannot see it.

Comment: Yes, the source code link above is just for Cert, go up one level to `Security`, that is included in Xamarin.iOS. Remember `Security` is not a typical framework, its public APIs are defined by C header files (`*.h`), you can open them in Xcode to review them, Xamarin wraps those for use from C#/F#

Comment: @SushiHangover I added device logs to the answer.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It explicitly says you are missing entitlements.

Comment: @Cheesebaron can be this error related to keychain access? Because in XCode you can use it with a free account but in VS Mac it is not possible.

Comment: Have you added the keychain entitlement? It is often needed for running on simulators.

Comment: @Cheesebaron yes, but it gave me the "could not found provisioning profile" error. So after I set development certificates, it works. I think Visual Studio Mac does not support free developer account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I will answer my own questions since I found the solution. The reason behind the problem is SecKeyRef using KeyChain access to  read and write key as stated in official documentation:

> A SecKeyRef instance that represents a key that is stored in a
> keychain can be safely cast to a SecKeychainItemRef for manipulation
> as a keychain item. On the other hand, if the key is not stored in a
> keychain, casting the object to a SecKeychainItemRef and passing it to
> Keychain Services functions returns errors.

Having a provisioning profile in Xcode to use SecKeyRef is not important, but in Visual Studio Mac, it is required to use Entitlements.plist to enable keychain access. So if your binding library used the SecKey API, you need to enable KeyChain Access in Entitlements.plist and set apple developer account in project.

```
<key>keychain-access-groups</key>
<array>
    <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.company.yourapp</string>
</array>
```